# Querying on count value having ()

Tags: count, left-join, inner-join, having-clause

I'm having difficulty with a query which displays records according to their fill rate.

For instance, a vacancy can have no bookings or some bookings. If a vacancy has bookings, they can be in the form of 'active [1]', 'pending [0]'. The query I have written so far works if the vacancy has booking records but I can't get it to work if it doesn't have booking records.

My query (which works) for vacancies with a booking is as follows:-

```
SELECT v.*, j.job_category_name, bu.business_unit_name 
FROM vacancy v 
INNER JOIN job_category j ON j.job_category_id = v.job_category_id 
INNER JOIN business_unit bu ON bu.business_unit_id = v.business_unit_id 
INNER JOIN booking b ON b.vacancy_id = v.vacancy_id 
INNER JOIN booking_status bs ON bs.id = b.booking_status_id 
WHERE 
    v.vacancy_status <> 'revoked' AND 
    v.vacancy_reference <> 'auto-generated booking' AND 
    v.business_unit_id IN (series of primary keys) AND 
(bs.booking_status_type_id = 1 OR bs.booking_status_type_id = 2) 
GROUP BY v.vacancy_id 
HAVING v.vacancy_limit > count(b.booking_id)
ORDER BY v.vacancy_id DESC
```

I thought by changing the join of b and bs to LEFT JOIN would have worked, but it hasn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a copy of your schema to work from, it's difficult to tell exactly, but when you changed `booking` and `bookingstatus` to `LEFT JOIN`s, did you also modify your `WHERE` clause so that it read something like:

```
WHERE 
  v.vacancy_status <> 'revoked' AND 
  v.vacancy_reference <> 'auto-generated booking' AND 
  v.business_unit_id IN (series of primary keys) AND 
  (ISNULL(bs.booking_status_type_id, 1) = 1 OR ISNULL(bs.booking_status_type_id, 2) = 2)
```

i.e. Ensured that the full WHERE clause would be satisfied, thus not stripping out the records where all the values for columns from `booking` and `bookingstatus` were NULL?

Comment: I'm just in the process of attempting to use ISNULL options, thanks.

Comment: @user275074, note that if the `booking_status_type_id` field is ever NULL in your actual data, the query won't behave as you'd expect as it'll treat those rows as if they had a `booking_status_type_id` of 1 or 2, so you'd probably want to tweak your query slightly rather than just use the exact one I wrote above, if it works for you =)

Comment: booking_status_type_id will never be null, it will only ever be 1,2,3 or 4

Comment: @user275074, not a problem then =)

Comment: Great, I added a comment below for how it is working with the two suggestions.

Comment: Hmmmmm I'm getting inconsistencies in results being returned.....

If I use create a booking for a vacancy but don't fill the vacancy limit, using (ISNULL(bs.booking_status_type_id) = 1 OR ISNULL(bs.booking_status_type_id = 2)) doesn't work. But it will work for when a vacancy has been created without adding bookings.

If I remove the IFNULL operators, a vacancy without bookings will work.

Comment: Rob, your comment about NULL values is correct, as one instance the LEFT JOIN could return NULL Values.......hmmmm

Comment: For reference purposes I changed the query to utilise IFNULL ((IFNULL(bs.booking_status_type_id, 1) = 1 OR IFNULL(bs.booking_status_type_id, 2) = 2))

Answer (score 0):

Try LEFT OUTER JOIN for the tables for which the joins may return 0 matches. 
For eg:- in your case have LEFT OUTER JOIN for b and bs and check

Comment: If I use LEFT OUTER JOIN with a combination of (ISNULL(bs.booking_status_type_id) = 1 OR ISNULL(bs.booking_status_type_id) = 2) for unfilled vacancies the query works.

To get it to function when querying for filled vacancies I need to keep the LEFT OUTER JOIN and use (bs.booking_status_type_id = 1 OR bs.booking_status_type_id = 2)  instead.

Comment: What is the reason that this query will work with left outer join but not with left join?